# How do I set the Image source to something other than File in Xamarin?

Tags: image, button, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get my Button Image to display which is stored as a byte array in a sql server. I can set an image file which is stored on the device in the root directory on the UWP device.

```
    <Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="Test Me">
        <Button.Image>
            <FileImageSource File="Forward.png" />
        </Button.Image>
    </Button>
```

or

```
MyButton.Image = "Forward.png";
```

...works fine. I am trying to do **Image.FromStream** or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the byte array from your database and pass it in this code.

```
 public static Image ConvertBinaryToImage(byte[] data)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

It will return the image and then you can bind it to your button.

Comment: What Library Do I get Image from?

Comment: Use System.Drawing